# div overlay for blocking clickable events iframe not working in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, iframe

I have an Iframe displaying webpages and I need to block all click events for that page. I used the following code

```
 <div id="IframeWrapper" style="position: relative;">
    <div id="iframeBlocker" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width:95%; height:95%;z-index:2"></div>
     <iframe  id="iframewebpage" style="z-index:1"  runat="server"></iframe>
    </div>
```

This works fine for all browsers except IE( both 8 and 9). any workarounds ?

Comment: which IE version are we talking about? And what about adding a z-index higher than the iframes' z-index?

Comment: It doesnt work for both 8 and 9 versions.. I tried with the z-index too( see my edit). That doesnt help either.

Comment: if it's an older version of ie, you may need to set the background of the frame blocker to a 50x50 transparent gif

Comment: @Pete: Cant use a gif.. since this iframe is acutally dragabble and size can be canged too.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure why the above doesn't work, the theory all looks correct to me, but when setting the background it appears to render the div successfully. Although the below code will not allow you to use the scrollbars either on the iframe it should be an OK starting point. I've removed the z-index as rendering the blocker after the iframe means it will be rendered "on top" of it.

```
<div id="IframeWrapper" style="position: relative;">
    <iframe  id="iframewebpage" style="z-index:1"  runat="server" src="http://www.w3schools.com" ></iframe>
    <div id="iframeBlocker" style="position:absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width:95%; height:95%;background-color:aliceblue;opacity:0.1;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: But this doesnt help for IE :(

Answer (score 4):

On the div containing "position: absolute", you need to add these styles:

```
{
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Yeah, IE is always weird.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and i manage to solve it by setting a height and widht to div="IframeWrapper" and after that it worked! :-)

/Andreas